# Qt, Qmake and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dll, qmake

I'm currenlty working on a portable project. To make it easier to compile on linux and windows, I'd like to use a .pro file which will generate a Makefile on linux and a visual studio project on windows.

But, I'm facing a problem on a very basic example.

Here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE        = app
TARGET          = client
CONFIG          += debug
SOURCES         += src/main.cpp
```

My main.cpp only contains an empty main:

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

Then, I just open my visual studio console, cd in my project folder and run `qmake.exe -spec win32-msvc2013 -tp vc`.

This generates the expected vcxproj file, that I can open with visual studio.

The program compiles well with visual, but I got a fail during the execution: `Qt5Cored.dll missing`.

I've verified:

- In the project properties, Qt lib directory has been added to the libraries directories
- Qt5Cored.dll exists (and is located in the Qt lib directory)
- I'm compiling and executing in debug environment

Additionnal information:

- Qt is well installed
- When I create a Qt5 project via visual studio, it works well (but this is not what I want).

When I manually import the .pro file using the Qt add-in, the vcxproj generated works well (no error during the execution): what's the difference? why the qmake doesn't work, but manual import does? Have I missed something to make the qmake work?

Comment: Qt5Cored.dll is placed inside the "bin" directory of the Qt installation. To run without problems you can add to your PATH Qt bin directory, but don't forget in the future that you did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone has said in the comments of my question, the solution is pretty simple: I just needed to add the Qt bin path to the Windows PATH environment variable.

Problem solved :)

Comment: Don't forget to attach qt *.dll files to your release .exe if you want to run your app on different pc without Qt